# The reason for not submitting one of the tables from the database

Tags: php, model-view-controller

```
    $sql = "select * from tbl_user"; 
    $result = $this->doSelect($sql); 
    foreach ($result as $key => $row) { 
        $sql = "select * from tbl_comment order by id desc"; 
        $result = $this->doSelect($sql); 
        $result[$key]['idduc'] = $result; 
    } 
    return $result; 
}
```

Comment: In future please [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping on a variable called `$result`, from the first query.

In the second query you destroy `$result` by reusing it in the second query processing. Also you then destroy that `$result` by assigning things to it as an array you want to return.

So use a different variable for the inner look like this

```
    $sql = "select * from tbl_user"; 
    $result = $this->doSelect($sql); 
    foreach ($result as $key => $row) { 
        $sql = "select * from tbl_comment order by id desc"; 
        $result1 = $this->doSelect($sql); 
        $return[$key]['idduc'] = $result1; 
    } 
    return $return; 
}
```